# An error occurred during local report processing in setparameters

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I am trying to process a local report but getting errors in setparameters.
here is the sample code.

r.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local

```
    Dim lr As LocalReport = r.LocalReport

    lr.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Gy.Report1.rdlc"
```

'note report is blank.

```
    Dim dss As New DataSet
    Dim daa As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from c_inventory", cn)
    cn.Open()
    daa.Fill(dss, "c_inventory")
    cn.Close()

    Dim dss1 As New ReportDataSource
    dss1.Name = "c_inventory"
    dss1.Value = dss.Tables("c_inventory")

    lr.DataSources.Add(dss1)
    r.RefreshReport()


    'Create a report parameter for the sales order number 
    Dim rpfilled As New ReportParameter()
    rpfilled.Name = "filled"
    rpfilled.Values.Add("0")


    Dim param() As ReportParameter = {rpfilled}
    lr.SetParameters(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally set my report parameters in local processing mode so

```
Dim p As New ReportParameter("myParameterName", param1.ToString())
rptViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(New () {p})
```

So try to changing your last 2 lines to

```
Dim param As New ReportParameter("yourReportParametername", rpfilled)
lr.LocalReport.SetParameters(New () {param})
```

Comment: what's the difference?